# Python threading ssh connections yields interference?

Tags: python, multithreading, ssh

I am using python to script some basic check-ins on remote servers using SSH. The server initializing the check-ins uses SSH keys to authenticate on all the remote servers. Everything works fine when I check the servers sequentially, but for efficiency I would like to run checks in parallel, and it seems when I do that the threads are stepping on each other.

I have simplified my code to the following to demonstrate the issue:

```
import threading
import os


def ssh_command(remote_ip):
    result = os.popen("ssh root@{} echo 'Hello World!' > temp.txt; cat temp.txt; rm temp.txt".format(remote_ip)).read()
    print(result)
    return

ip_list = [1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8]     # Of course these are just placeholder IPs

# Sequential Example
for ip in ip_list:
    ssh_command(ip)
    # Running this I get "Hello World!" printed from each remote server

# Multi-threaded Example
thread_list = []
for ip in ip_list:
    t = threading.Thread(target=ssh_command, args=[ip])
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    thread_list.append(t)
for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()
# This usually works fine for one or some machines but most error with either:
# "cat: temp.txt: No such file or directory"
# and/or
# "rm: cannot remove 'temp.txt': No such file or directory
```

So it looks to me like the threads are interfering, e.g. the `rm temp.txt` from the first thread may somehow also be getting executed in the second thread so when the second thread tries to `cat` or `rm` temp.txt the file doesn't exist.

I decided to test that theory by removing the `rm temp.txt` part of the command and indeed I get 2 `Hello World!`s printed. So while it does seem I could just remove any destructive commands (or perhaps move them to a separate threading loop to clean after all threads are done), I would still like to understand why these threads seem to be interfering. Ideally I would also like to find a work-around since modifying the remote command to avoid local interference seems counter-intuitive and unreliable.

I have seem a few related posts to issues like this, but most seem to be using *paramiko*, which I have considered using but I don't think it should be necessary in this case so I'd like to avoid it if possible. I'm typically of the opinion that packages should not be used if they can be easily avoided to reduce dependencies / complexity etc.

Just in case it comes up, I have also tried switching to python `multithreading` since I thought the sub-processes would be more divided, but I get the same result. I'm guessing this may have something to do with buffering in ssh but anything there is above my pay grade :P

Any help or direction to investigate will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not 100% sure but i think the problem happends because your command is partially executed locally

In this line:

```
result = os.popen("ssh root@{} echo 'Hello World!' > temp.txt; cat temp.txt; rm temp.txt".format(remote_ip)
```

you use ; and > to seperate commands. you execute the following commands:

1)`ssh root@{} echo 'Hello World!'` this runs on the remote server

2) `> temp.txt` take the output of first command and save it to a **local** file called temp.txt

3)`cat temp.txt` read the **local** file called temp.txt

4) `rm temp.txt` delete the **local** filed called temp.txt

so all but the first command are executed locally and so you have 2 threads attempting to create and delete the same file on the same computer.

i guess you wanted all the commands to be executed remotely, so try putting `"` around the whole command like this

```
result = os.popen("ssh root@{} \"echo 'Hello World!' > temp.txt; cat temp.txt; rm temp.txt\"".format(remote_ip)
```

Comment: Trying now... I didn't realize `>` actually split commands, I thought it just redirected output. Also any idea why this would work fine sequentially? Keep in mind that is just a demonstration command, my actual remote command is monitoring for netflow and I would know if it was just reading local netflow so it definitely runs everything on the remote server.

Comment: Well escaping `awk` quotes was a pain in the arse, but that does seem to have fixed it. Gotta say I feel a little dumb for that one. Any idea why the extra quotes were needed for running in threads or separate processes but not sequentially?

Comment: because when you use the same local file in parallel there can be a race like so:  (1) thread1 creates the file and writes to it then (2) thread2 override the file then (3) thread1 deletes the file and then (4) thread2 attempt to delete the same file but fails because it was already deleted

Comment: Ah it just clicked for me, the mistake I was making is I thought temp.txt was being created on the *remote* server, i.e. I thought everything after `root@{}` would be passed as the `[command]` argument of `ssh` when actually as you stated the `>` takes the ssh command's output and prints to a *local* temp.txt. Adding the quotes makes ssh create temp.txt on the *remote* server as originally intended which solves the issue when running in parallel

Answer (score 0):

you could also try

```
def ssh_command(remote_ip):
    result = os.popen("ssh root@{} echo 'Hello World!' > temp.txt; cat temp{}.txt; rm temp{}.txt".format(remote_ip, remote_ip, remote_ip)).read()
    print(result)
    return
```

the problem is that all threads write to and delete the same local file. If you do ths sequentially there is no problem - temp.txt gets created locally read out and deleted and again. But when run with several threads each one opens the same file and writes to the same file, reads the same file and deletes it. 
This means what ever thread tries to run the `cat` will only see the file that the last thread before has created ,but very likely not his own version of the file (that has already been over-written). 
And then you delete the file. So until still another thread recreates it any thread that has not yet reached the `cat` will no longer find a temp.txt.

By changing `temp.txt` to e.g. `temp127.0.0.1.txt` (when ip requested was 127.0.0.1) you create one file per IP and the problem is solved. Unless you call the same ip with two different threads.

Comment: Good idea, as I commented on DorElias' post, adding quotes makes `ssh` create temp.txt on the remote server which is what I originally thought was happening, but this method also solves the issue by just using a different local file per thread.